# React onclick event not responding

Tags: reactjs

React newbie here.

Not sure why but these onclick events are not firing for me.

I'm importing this class into a main class so maybe my main class can't read the functions inside or something?

```
var React = require('react');
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class TableDataRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

    handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

    render() {


        const item = this.props.item;

        var columns = Object.keys(item).map(function(key) {
          return <td value={key}>{item[key]}</td>
        });

        return (
            <tr>
                {columns}
                <td>
                    <button className="ui button edit blue" value="{item.id}">
                        <i className="edit icon"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="ui button delete red" value="{item.id}">
                        <i className="delete icon"></i>
                        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
module.exports = TableDataRow;
```

Comment: Inisde your handClick , do it like this  `handleClick() { this.setState({ do anything here })}`   make sure to put curly braces around prevState as well

Comment: Did you try adding a console log within the handleClick() method and check if it gets printed?

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe you could provide more info about how this component is used in other component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var React = require('react');
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class TableDataRow extends React.Component {
  // you don't need constructor just for initial states
  state = {isToggleOn: true};

  // Use arrow function and get lexical binding
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn})
  }

  render() {
    // Do object destructuring, so from now on
    // item will be referred to this.props.item
    const {item} = this.props;
    const {isToggleOn} = this.state;

    return (
        <tr>
          { Object.keys(item).map(key => <td value={key}>{item[key]}</td>) }
          <td>
              <button className="ui button edit blue" value={item.id}>
                  <i className="edit icon"></i>
              </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="ui button delete red" value={item.id}>
                <i className="delete icon"></i>
                {isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
    );
  }
}
module.exports = TableDataRow;
```

Using arrow function creates lexical binding, which means it is always binded to where it was defined, that way you don't need to bind it in constructor - cleaner code.

[This article explains all the different ways of handling 'this'](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

When you do `var item = this.props.item`, you're creating another copy of item. This can be achieved through **destructuring**: `const {item} = this.props`. Notice how I also destructured `isToggleOn`.

[Simple intro to object destructuring](http://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/)

Lastly using `.map` and arrow function you can achieve some really clean code as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
this.setState(({prevState}) => ({
  isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
});
```

instead of

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind the handleClick to this:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className="ui button delete red" value="{item.id}">
   <i className="delete icon"></i>
       {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
</button>
```